# How do I restrict Sitecore authors to only be able to edit items they created?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is there a way to tell Sitecore (using workflow or some other way) that a user should only be able to modify the items that they created in Sitecore?

My only way that I can think of to do it is to create a folder for each user that they have rights to and then use Sitecore Queries to gather the items for consumption on the website. That of course is not automatic and doesn't scale to a lot of content creators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use workflow to achive this.

Create a custom action to do the following:

1. Get the item
2. Get the sitecore authoring role
3. Remove inheritance for Write, Rename, Delete for the sitecore authoring role
4. Add Write, Rename, Delete for the specific user
5. Add the action to the initial step of you workflow
6. add the workflow as the default workflow for your items (set it in the standard values for your templates)

Comment: Sounds great, I just didn't want to write code if there was some way to do it in configuration. Thanks!

Comment: It would have been nice. I think with sitecore you don't get a lot of features out of the box but on the other hand it's really customisable and you can do almost anything pretty easily.